# How to optimize $in query performance in mongodb using an index?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am doing an `$in` query in a mongodb cluster in my application. Below is an extract from the query details shown in mongodb atlas for this query.

```
{
  "command": {
    "find": "orders",
    "filter": {
      "owner": "testowner",
      "reference": {
        "$in": [
          "123",
          "456",
          "... about 1000 more refs"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "planSummary": "IXSCAN { owner: 1, reference: 1, createdTimestamp: -1 }",
  "keysExamined": 10841,
  "docsExamined": 101,
  "hasSortStage": true,
  "fromMultiPlanner": true,
  "numYields": 393,
  "nreturned": 101,
  "reslen": 53913,
  "durationMillis": 6820
}
```

Even though the query has used my index, keys examined to docs returned ratio is high, and the query has taken about 7 seconds.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can improve the performance of this query?

Comment: 10k keysExamined doesn't look that much, and 101 docsExamined indicates good selectivity. What "executionStats" says?  Does mongo have enough memory? what db.serverStatus().wiredTiger says about cache and capacity?  Could you help to reproduce it in isolation? Like version of the db, shape of the documents in mgeneratejs or mgodatagen format, indexes, etc? It might be the case to raise on mongodb jira, if it is reproducible.